# Android хранение текстов запросов

Tags: android, sqlite

Подскажите пожалуйста, как правильно хранить в android приложении тексты запросов.

Я использую непростые запросы с временными таблицами и тд. С ними не удобно работать через класс SQLiteQueryBuilder. Есть ли оптимальный способ как можно хранить тексты запросов в читабельном виде и быстро получить их когда нужно?

Comment: Чем SharedPreferences не устраивает?

Comment: @DrMcSheen сейчас им пользуюсь. Только есть проблема нужно всегда иметь context под рукой.